# How do I send PyAudio data over the internet using Socket with Python?

Tags: python

So … My first question on Stack Overflow, and oh boy is it a shocker. I use Python for my everyday programming, and my latest project is a voice chatting app. I need to use PyAudio to record the data I'll send, and I have successfully recorded things in the past with PyAudio, so that's not the problem. The next part is. *I have no idea how to use Socket!*

Can someone try and give me some code to assist with my troubles? And before you go and say, "Go read a tutorial!", I have *tried* to do that, and my brain just about exploded. So can someone please assist?

To show I'm not *completely* helpless, here is some code to record 10 seconds of audio and save it as a .wav file to the same place as where the .py while is saved:

```
import pyaudio
import wave

chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
channels = 1
fs = 44100  # Record at 44100 samples per second
seconds = 10
filename = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio

print('Recording')

stream = p.open(format=sample_format,
                channels=channels,
                rate=fs,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk,
                input=True)

frames = []  # Initialize array to store frames

# Store data in chunks for 10 seconds
for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    frames.append(data)

# Stop and close the stream 
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
# Terminate the PortAudio interface
p.terminate()

print('Finished recording')

# Save the recorded data as a WAV file
wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(channels)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(sample_format))
wf.setframerate(fs)
```

That's about it... have a nice day!

PS: To change the amount of seconds the above script records for, change the variable 'seconds' from ten to whtever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like your main struggle is with transferring your file/data via some network protocol, I will illustrate the concept using [ZeroMQ](https://zeromq.org/) just because it has less overhead so we can focus on the important stuff. You can install it using `pip install zmq`.

First, make sure the file you are writing is closed:

```
wf.close()
```

After that you can send the file content using the following snippet:

```
import zmq
         
PORT = 12345  # must match the receiver port
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.connect(f'tcp://localhost:{PORT}')
                                                                                      
with open('output.wav', 'rb') as in_file:
    file_content = in_file.read()
                                                                                      
print(f'Sending {len(file_content)} bytes.')                                        
socket.send(file_content)
```

The receiver part can be implemented like this:

```
import zmq
                                                                                  
PORT = 12345  # must match the sender port
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.bind(f'tcp://*:{PORT}')

msg = socket.recv()                                                            
print(f'Received {len(msg)} bytes.')
```

If you now run the sender and the receiver in two separate terminals, you will (ideally) see that the data sent by the sender are received by the receiver. You can write them to a file and/or play them.
You can do the same with the vanilla `socket` with a little bit more overhead to set things up and to gather data split up into smaller chunks.
Either way you will have to decide how to deal with the bidirectional communication. You will have to do the sending and receiving in infinite loops, to. The code above just shows a single data transfer.

Comment: Please don't get confused by my wording. In case you work under Linux, you would open two terminals (or more precisely: terminal emulators) and then fire off your sender and your receiver applications, respectively. Whatever OS you use, just start the two applications so they can communicate.